# Looking for a less network intensive way to pass json documents

Tags: python, json

I have to send allot of very structured jsondata between services and I can see that network becomes a bottlenected. I have zipped the data and saved memory in that way. But I wondered if there is a protocol where a list of json documents is split into schema and data in transit and converted back to json documents when it arrives. Such that the keys don't need to send in each object and only the payload data needs to be send.

I imagine something like this.

**Raw json**

```
[{'a': 1, 'b': [{'c': 3}]},
 {'a': 2, 'b': [{'c': 3}]},
 {'a': 1, 'b': [{'c': 4}]},
 {'a': 2, 'b': [{'c': 3}]}]
```

**Converted json**

```
{'schema': ['a', ['b', ['c']]],
 'data': [[1, [3]], [2, [3]], [1, [4]], [2, [3]]]}
```

Don't look to much on the example, it is not an attempt to actually implement the algorithm. I wanted to illustrate an example of how I envision the conversion. I'm looking for a protocol where I can install incoders and decoders and not looking to implement my own compression protocol.

Comment: Try alternate data formats like [Avro](https://avro.apache.org/docs/current/)

Comment: Thank you very much it was exactly what I was looking for

Comment: Compress the json. It will shrink it nicely.